# Salesforce Events trackable without Event Monitoring add-on

Tags: appexchange, custom, eventlogfile, event-monitoring, tracking

Going over the Salesforce documentation, I have found that the only events that can be tracked **without Event Monitoring add-on** (so, in standard *Enterprise* and *Unlimited* orgs) are the following:

- Login Events
- Logout Events
- Insecure External Assets

I am wondering if there is a **workaround** way (or a 3rd party app) that would allow me to track and extrapolate some of the **other Event Types** (listed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_supportedeventtypes.htm)) without purchasing the Event Monitoring add-on?

Thanks!